# "No bluetooth adapter found" in linux mint 20.1

Tags: linux, linux-mint, drivers, bluetooth

I am new in linux mint. i just switched from windows to linux.
Now i could not enable my bluetooth. it shows no bluetooth adapter found.

[image]

I followed [**this link**](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=307781) to solve this but nothing solved.
I also tried with this command `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`

And i ensured that,
==> there is no physical bluetooth button.
==> no bios setting to enable or disable bluetooth.
==> Laptop model **hp15da1018TU**.
==> wirless card rtl8821ce.

Comment: I also have this issue. I am using a dual boot. Bluetooth in Windows work flawlessly. But in LinuxMint, it does not. I had this issue in every version of LinuxMint that I have used. I have tried many solutions from so many forums but none of them worked so far.

Answer (score -3):

Backup your Docs, Desktop, Downloads (if desired), & Pictures (if they're yours). Install Linux Mint 20. I've never seen a Bluetooth issue with this flavor.

Comment: I am on Linux Mint 20 and have this exact same Bluetooth problem.